# No decoration is dropped when the total length of the decoration list exceeds the length of the input path (a possible bug)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

Just want to run this by the good people of tex.stackexchange before I submit this as a bug.

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript featuring a pgf picture of a 2cm long horizontal line that is decorated by two built-in pgf decorations: `curveto` and `zigzag`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}
  \begin{pgfdecoration}{{curveto}{1cm},{zigzag}{2cm}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
  \end{pgfdecoration}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting picture is (not to scale)

[image: A line decorated with two pgf decorations.]

I expect no zigzag decoration, i.e I expect the following picture (to the same scale as before).

[image: No zigzag.]

The reason is the following paragraph from pp. 1002-1003 of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a describing the meaning of the environment

```
\begin{pgfdecoration}{{<decoration>}{<length>},{<decoration>}{<length>}}
   <environment contents>
\end{pgfdecoration}
```

(I've emphasized the significant part.)

> The input path is divided into input paths as follows: The first input
>   path consists of the first lines of the path specified in the
>   `〈environment contents〉` until the `〈length`〉of the first element of
>   the `〈decoration list〉` is reached. If this length is reached in the
>   middle of a line, the line is broken up at this exact position. Then
>   the second input path has the `〈length〉` of the second element in the
>   `〈decoration list〉` and consists of the lines making up the following
>   `〈length〉` part of the path in the `〈environment contents〉`, and so
>   on.
>
> **If the lengths in the `〈decoration list〉` do not add up to the total
>   length of the path in the `〈environment contents〉`, either some
>   decorations are dropped (if their lengths add up to more than the
>   length of the `〈environment contents〉`)** or the input path is not fully
>   used (if their lengths add up to less).

Since in the present case the lengths in the decoration list add up to 1cm+2cm=3cm, which is more than the length of the environment content, namely 2cm, one of the two decorations should be dropped. However, as the rendered picture shows, both decorations are used.

Comment: There is still some path left for the zigzag so it kicks in. That's probably why it is not dropped. I guess the manual says if there is no path left for the decoration it is dropped.

Comment: @percusse: Yeah, maybe you're right. Maybe the manual is simply not careful enough in specifying this step of the algorithm. Each item on the decoration list should be classified into one of 3 categories based on the accumulated length so far (including the item under consideration): (a) the acc. length doesn't exceed the environment content's length, (b) the item under consideration is the first one on the list such that the acc. length exceeds the environment content's length, (c) the rest of the items. The items of cat. c are dropped, but the item in cat. b simply gets its length shortened.

Comment: Maybe you can put it this way: If I want to decorate the whole path by `zigzag` I would write `\begin{pgfdecoration}{{zigzag}{10m}` so I do not have to measure the length by myself.

Comment: Check  the difference between `\pgfpoint{1.17cm}{0cm}` and `\pgfpoint{1.18cm}{0cm}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You mean as an argument to the `\pathlineto` command in the example I listed in my post?

Comment: Yes, naturally.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: OK I tried. Could you please help me and spell out the lesson to be learned from this experiment?

Comment: It shows that not the complete length of the decoration is meant by your quote but "one item".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, see my reply to percusse's comment. I think the algorithm described in that reply is the one that is actually used by pgf.